# Could we add and use a return address stack register to prevent stack overflow attack?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack-overflow

Coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248642/why-are-function-parameters-pushed-earlier-on-call-stack-than-the-return-address), would not it be more secure to push return address to a specific stack register, so that we can not exploit the stack overflow?

1. Caller pushes return address (by `call`) to a `return address stack register`.
2. Caller pushes arguments.
3. Callee pushes locals.
4. Some work in the callee is happening.
5. Callee cleans the stack.
6. `ret` pops the value of `return address stack register` into `RIP`/`EIP`.

Comment: Also, what is a stack _register_?

Comment: Forth does it that way, SPARC, too. You can easily do it on ARM and a few other architectures. Yes, it is possible. It is not usually done though, probably because it requires a more complicated programming model and the allocation of two stacks instead of just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the return address in a register instead of on the stack doesn't help in most cases.

Most RISC ISAs already do this with a link register, and their `call` equivalent is jump-and-link (MIPS `jal`) or ARM `bl`).  The callee has to save the return address on the stack themself if they want to call a child function, because `jal` clobbers the link register.  (So they eventually return by loading the return address into a register and using a jump-to-register instruction.)

This is not fundamentally different than what x86 does, where `ret` is basically `pop rip` directly.  The only difference would be leaf functions, where the return address never goes into memory unless the callee spills/reloads it to get an extra scratch register.